# Reverse scroll reveal script

Tags: jquery

I have a simple timeline that show info block when scrolling the page. The elements bounce in from each side while scrolling down. Right now the elements, when loaded, stays visible but I would like them to hide when not in view and re-appear the same way when I scroll back to top...

How can I modify the code in "reverse"?
Thank you for your help.

here is the code I use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var $timeline_block = $('.cd-timeline-block');

//hide timeline blocks which are outside the viewport
$timeline_block.each(function(){
    if($(this).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*0.75) {
        $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').addClass('is-hidden');
    }
});

//on scolling, show/animate timeline blocks when enter the viewport
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    $timeline_block.each(function(){
        if( $(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*0.75 && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img').hasClass('is-hidden') ) {
            $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('bounce-in');
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: So what's happening? they are being hidden when out of view, but not animating back in - just reappearing?

Comment: Exactly, they are not animating back. And they do not reappear either they stay visible.

Comment: Almost there - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwPPzE however, now when you scroll back down it doesn't fade in. It's all a bit confusing - so what I would suggest is create helper functions to check where the container is on the screen. If you only want 1 container to be on the screen at a time this should be relatively easy to check

Comment: Yes you are close! I tried your code on my timeline of 65+ objects and when scrolling down, after maybe 15 objects, it become really choppy.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the basic statements there, just roll up the behavior into a function, and call that function once when the page loads.

```
function onScroll() {
  $('.cd-timeline-block').each( function() {
    if( $(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*0.75 && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img').hasClass('is-hidden') ) {
      $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('bounce-in');
    } else {
      $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').addClass('is-hidden').removeClass('bounce-in');
    }
  });
};

$(window).scroll(onScroll);
$(onScroll);  // shorthand for $(document).ready(onScroll);
```

Comment: I think you are close here Travis but How can I enlarge the visible portion not affected by the function. Because right now I see only two element at the same time. And sometimes the elements are completely at the top, sometimes not even there...

Comment: Can you post a link or a JSFiddle?  I can't really give you an answer without seeing the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

When you hide the class you need to remove the `bounce-in` class. Otherwise, when you show it and add the `bounce-in` class the element already has it, so the animation will not run again.

For your viewport function:

```
$timeline_block.each(function(){
    if($(this).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*0.75) {
        var $block = $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content');
        $block.addClass('is-hidden');
        $block.removeClass('bounce-in');
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok now the elements disappear when I scroll up but its not exactly what I want. I would like the elements to disappear when not in view when I scroll down and then, when I scroll up again, reappear the same way they do when scrolling down.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Travis answer I added an **else if** statement which worked. Worth adding a class like 'bounce-off' as it isn't too smooth when it hides.

```
  function onScroll() {
  $('.cd-timeline-block').each( function() {
    if( $(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*0.75 && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img').hasClass('is-hidden') ) {
      $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('bounce-in');
    } else if($(this).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*0.75) {
      $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').addClass('is-hidden').removeClass('bounce-in');
    }
  });
};

$(window).scroll(onScroll);
$(onScroll);  // shorthand for $(document).ready(onScroll);
```